# Xcode 9 "Fix issue" shortcuts

Tags: xcode, xcode9

The fix issue shortcuts

- `⌃⌥⌘F` Fix All In Scope
- `⌃⌘'` Fix Next Issue
- `⌃⌘"` Fix Previous Issue

stopped working for me in Xcode 9. Also, the corresponding menu items show no effect.

Has somebody figured out how to do this?

**Edit:** Fixed as of Xcode 9.2

Comment: This seems to be a known bug. I reported it to the Apple bug reporter and it was marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Xcode's new default shortcut `⌘D` doesn't work for me either...